# How can I convert dictionary in list to dictionary in Python 3?

Tags: json, python-3.x

```
import urllib.request as request

import json

api = "https://kr.api.pvp.net/championmastery/location/KR/player/38281748/topchampions?api_key=RGAPI-6bdee369-a91d-485a-9280-444de0e37afe"

api_data = request.urlopen(api).read().decode("utf-8")

apiload = json.loads(api_data)

print(apiload)
```

---

I want to print my League of Legends champion Points.

So I use https://developer.riotgames.com/api/methods#!/1091/3768 this API, and

convert to Python object. but this API's Return Value is List[ChampionMasteryDTO],

which means I can't use it as dictionary.

apiload contain [{"key" : "value"}, ... {"key" : "value"}]

how can I make apiload as dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apiload variable prints two dictionaries within a list.

If you would like to create a new dictionary using the apiload you can do the following:

```
#create a new dictionary
my_dict = {}
#now iterate through the list
for item in apiload:
#now iterate through the dictionaries that are in the list:
  for key, value in item.items():
#assign the key value to the new declared dictionary
    new_dict[key] = value
```

This will create a new dictionary with the following output:

`championId : 91
tokensEarned : 0
championPointsSinceLastLevel : 339079
chestGranted : True
lastPlayTime : 1478451844000
playerId : 38281748
championLevel : 7
championPoints : 360679
championPointsUntilNextLevel : 0
championId : 5
tokensEarned : 0
championPointsSinceLastLevel : 129110
chestGranted : True
lastPlayTime : 1478454752000
playerId : 38281748
championLevel : 7
championPoints : 150710
championPointsUntilNextLevel : 0
championId : 21
tokensEarned : 0
championPointsSinceLastLevel : 2018
chestGranted : False
lastPlayTime : 1476197348000
playerId : 38281748
championLevel : 4
championPoints : 14618
championPointsUntilNextLevel : 6982`

Hope that helps.

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted. thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the structure of your response, the easy one if you just want to print your points, would be to just use a loop actually :

```
for el in apiload:
    print(el["championPoints"])
```

If your problem is to print the total of points collected, use a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) :

```
from collections import Counter

 cnt = Counter()
 for col in apiload:
     for k in col.keys():
         cnt[k] += c.get(k, 0)

 print(cnt['championPoints']) # should print the sum of championPoints
```

Comment: I don't even think about using list like this. thank you for noticing me.